# WO: Make asset XY trump service address XY -- if asset's geometry type is point

Tags: maximo

Maximo 7.6.1.1:

I have custom fields in ASSET:

1. `ASSET.GEOMETRYTYPE`

   - Values: POINT, LINE, POLYGON
   - Source: JSON mapping
2. `ASSET.X` and `ASSET.Y`

   - The values are the centerpoints of GIS assets.
   - Source: points = [ST_X](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-x.htm) & [ST_Y](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-y.htm), line = [ArcPy scheduled task](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/345110/135445), polygon = [ST_PointOnSurface](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/356886/135445)

---

In a WO, if the asset's GEOMETRYTYPE = POINT, then I want the asset's XY to trump the service asset's XY (when auto-locating in the map).

- This would apply to the current record's blue map pin as well as with auto-create spatial.
- More information about the OOB logic here: [Automatic location search order process for work orders](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSG2D3_7.6.0/com.ibm.spl.doc/plussmngr/r_auto_loc_wo_search.html)
- This scenario would **not** apply to other geometry types like lines or polygons. Those assets are large and the service address' XY would be more precise/meaningful than the center point of a line or polygon (unlike points).

---

For example, if a tree pruning WO is created from an SR, then the WO will likely have a service address specified.

At some point in the workflow, a forestry supervisor will specify the tree asset in the WO. The tree's XY will be more meaningful and precise than the service address's XY. So we want the tree asset's XY to trump the service address's XY.

---

**Is there a way to make a WO asset's XY trump the service address' XY -- if the asset's geometry type is a point?**

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a simple automation script (with an attribute launch point):

- Object: WORKORDER
- Attribute: ASSETNUM
- Events: Run action

---

```
if mbo.getString("ASSET.GEOMETRYTYPE") == "POINT":
    mbo.setValue("SERVICEADDRESS.LONGITUDEX", None)
    mbo.setValue("SERVICEADDRESS.LATITUDEY", None)
```

If the asset's geometry type is a point, then it nulls out the service address' XY.

---

Note:

It sounds like IBM plans to implement something like this in OOB Maximo:

> "Configurable auto-locate order and flexible hierarchy"
>
> Source: [Roadmap: IBM Maximo Location Based Services](https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.guidebook.com/upload/152239/BBf30VMQzP0bhcWy0PMjAPkUurSPVeYkMdSe.pdf) (excerpt [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmPee.png)).

But rumour has it that IBM has been talking about this for several years, but has not yet implemented it.